# Populating map in AsyncTask need to touch screen to see points

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mapview

I am having an issue with my mapview - I populate it with a AsyncTask, but after it completes the points don't show up until the screen is tapped (after the first touch all the points show up properly).

Oncreate:

> dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyMap.this, "Populating Map",
>                 "Please wait...", true);
>
> new AddOverlays().execute();

My AsyncTask:

```
class AddOverlays extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {

                //do my looping work to add items to map

            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);   

            String nothing = "";
            return nothing;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use the `AsyncTask` as a inner class in your `MapActivity` or are you using a `Service` to run the task? If so, how do you pass the `MapView` reference over in an intent since it is not serializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling:
`invalidate()` from UI thread
or
`postInvalidate()` from another thread

on your MapView object to make the map view repaint.

You should call `mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);` in `onPostExecute(String sResponse)` as adding a new overlay is not an expensive operation.

I suppose you will do some kind of expensive operation in `doInBackground(Void... unused)` because as of right now you don't really need the whole AddOverlays task.

Comment: I had the add in the onPostExecute, but that didn't solve so I moved back (will put it back).  Yes there is a lot heavy lifting going on in the doInBackground.  RE: invalidate or PostInvalidate - do you mean in the onCreate of this mapview?  Could you give an example?

Comment: Can I add the postInvalidate to the onPostExecute?  If so how?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` just call `mapView.invalidate()` where the mapView variable is a reference to your MapView object :)